# nfs over usb beaglebone black linux

Tags: linux-kernel, usb, nfs, u-boot, tftp

I'm trying to boot nfs over usb. Till now I'm able to load the kernel and run it with dtb using tftp over ethernet usb. I'm passing

```
setenv bootargs console=ttyO0,115200n8 root=/dev/nfs rw rootfstype=ext4 rootwait fixrtc nfsroot=192.168.2.1:/home/mahathug/tftp/fs ip=192.168.2.2:192.168.2.1:192.168.2.1:255.255.255.0 nfsrootdebug earlyprintk

net eth0: initializing cpsw version 1.12 (0)  
[    4.045127] net eth0: phy found : id is : 0x7c0f1  
[    4.050156] libphy: PHY 4a101000.mdio:01 not found  
[    4.055215] net eth0: phy 4a101000.mdio:01 not found on slave 1  
[    4.068127] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): eth0: link is not ready  
[   14.064781] Waiting up to 110 more seconds for network.  
[   24.064774] Waiting up to 100 more seconds for network.  
[   34.064773] Waiting up to 90 more seconds for network.  
[   44.064774] Waiting up to 80 more seconds for network.  
[   54.064774] Waiting up to 70 more seconds for network.  
[   64.064773] Waiting up to 60 more seconds for network.  
[   74.064773] Waiting up to 50 more seconds for network.  
[   84.064773] Waiting up to 40 more seconds for network.  
[   94.064773] Waiting up to 30 more seconds for network.  
[  104.064773] Waiting up to 20 more seconds for network.  
[  114.064773] Waiting up to 10 more seconds for network.  
[  124.064775] Waiting up to 0 more seconds for network.  
[  124.084994] IP-Config: Complete:  
[  124.088391]      device=eth0, hwaddr=c8:df:84:d6:06:9c, ipaddr=192.168.2.2, mask=255.255.255.0, gw=192.168.2.1  
[  124.098930]      host=192.168.2.2, domain=, nis-domain=(none)  
[  124.104988]      bootserver=192.168.2.1, rootserver=192.168.2.1, rootpath=
```

which won't work any way.

this doesn't work as i have not connected ethernet cable and it will search for phy ethernet but I tried appending `::usb0` to ip parameter in above command it doesn't search for ethernet but still getting error

```
Root-NFS: nfsroot=/home/mahathug/tftp/fs  
[   16.081175] NFS: nfs mount
opts='vers=2,udp,rsize=4096,wsize=4096,nolock,addr=192.168.2.1'  
[   16.089933] NFS:   parsing nfs mount option 'vers=2'  
[   16.095210] NFS:   parsing nfs mount option 'udp'  
[   16.100145] NFS:   parsing nfs mount option 'rsize=4096'  
[   16.105741] NFS:   parsing nfs mount option 'wsize=4096'  
[   16.111314] NFS:   parsing nfs mount option 'nolock'  
[   16.116537] NFS:   parsing nfs mount option 'addr=192.168.2.1'  
[   16.122670] NFS: MNTPATH: '/home/mahathug/tftp/fs'  
[   16.127718] NFS: sending MNT request for 192.168.2.1:/home/mahathug/tftp/fs  
[   16.135554] NFS: failed to create MNT RPC client, status=-101    
[   16.141588] NFS: unable to mount server 192.168.2.1, error -101**
```

Any hints, or way to debuf these.

I don't get any logs /var/log/syslog on host machine after tftp transfer

I have Enable usb_eth option in kernel configuration and all other needed as root_nfs and etc.

I dont want to use ethernet cable seperately. I want to do it over usb

Comment: I was able to mount nfs through ethernet. Yet, I'm failing to mount it over USB with eroor failed to create MNT RPC client, status=-101. Any pointers?

Answer (score 0):

I know this is old. I could be wrong but I think the USB port doesn't get fully initiated until after the OS is loaded.  Even if it did load sooner, your status shows that you are still pointing to the eth0 for a boot devices.  Seems that this should be usb0 in the uEnv.txt, but when I tried it I got
starting USB...
USB0: usb0 not available.